# How to get a struct from view! call in near_sdk_sim?

Tags: nearprotocol

I have a following method:

```
pub fn get_product(&self, product_id: U128) -> Product {
        let product_option = self.product_map.get(&product_id);
        match product_option {
            Some(product) => product,
            None => {
                panic!("No products for the id");
            }
        }
    }
```

Product struct:

```
#[derive(Default, BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize)]
#[derive(serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
pub struct Product {
    pub user_id: u128,
    pub product_details_hash: String, 
}
```

When I call in near_sdk_sim I get error

```
let product:Product = view!(contract.get_product(1.into())).unwrap_json();
```

Error is:

```
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Error("EOF while parsing a value", line: 1, column: 0)
```

How can I get the struct from the view! call?

Answer (score 1):

For future reference questions of this nature are better suited as an issue[`near-sdk-rs`](https://github.com/near/near-sdk-rs/issues) .

My guess for this issue is that the call paniced and thus there was no value to deserialize. Try checking if it is okay.

```rust
let res = view!(contract.get_product(1.into()));
assert!(res.is_ok());
```